# sending a value from drop down box to another page

Tags: php, html

I have the following drop down box. I want to be able to select a value from this box and using Php sending it to another page.

this is my current code for drop dwon box:

version2:

```
<form style="margin-top:20px; margin-right:+50px" name="formname" method="post" action="search.php">
<div class="controls controls-row">
<select name="select1" id="select1"> 
<option value="SelectIsland">Select your island</option>
<option value="stMaarten">St. Maarten</option>
<option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
<option value="Curacou">Curacou</option>
<option value="StBarths">St. Barths</option>
</select>   

<select name="select2"> 
<option value="SelectLoc">Select your location</option>
<option value="Philipsburg">Philipsburg</option>
<option value="SimpsonBay">Simpson Bay</option>
<option value="Maho">Maho</option>
<option value="Cupecoy">Cupecoy</option>
<option value="Middleregion">Middle region</option>
<option value="MadameEstate">Madame Estate</option>
<option value="StPeters">St. Peters</option>
<option value="DawnBeach">Dawn Beach</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Find Restaurant" style="margin-top:-10px; margin-right:0px" />
</div>
<?php 
$select1 = $_POST['select1'];
?>
</form>
```

I am trying to pass $select1 to search.php, using this: $select1 = $_POST['select1'];

however I get this following error, without doing anything:
 Notice: Undefined index: select1 in C:\wamp\www\iLandgrub.com V 1.2\main page\index.php on line 194, on y index.php.

If I remove  $select1 = $_POST['select1']; then it will work but on search.php I dont get the values I wanted.

this my code in search.php:

the same applies for select2, as well. I am already in my index.php withut doing anything I get the error Undefined index.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['select1']) && isset($_POST['select2'])) {
$select1 = $_GET['select1'];
$select2 = $_GET['select2'];
echo $select1;
echo "";
echo $select2;
}
else{
echo "not set";
}
?>
```

[image]
this is the error in index.php, when you go to this page.

Comment: On what page do you get the error? `search.php`?

Comment: These post variables should be referred to in search.php (see the first line, `<form ... action="search.php">`. You also need `<input type="submit">` on the page with form.

Comment: i get the error on on the same page, it doesnt go search.php

Comment: can you tell us about your directory structure?

Comment: very simple, there is an index, where you have to select your island and location. then they need to be send to another page search.php where you do work with them. on my index.php I only have these there because the main comes in search.php . this is what I have on my search.php: <?php
                      if(isset($_GET['select1']) && isset($_GET['select2'])) {
 $select1 = $_GET['select1'];
 $select2 = $_GET['select2'];
 echo $select1;
   echo "";
   echo $select2;
 }
 else{
   echo "not set";
 }
 
?>  this one works when it goes to else. by if I get an error.

Comment: @S.N and there's your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're using an anchor element. Change

```
<a href="search.php" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:-10px; margin-right:0px"type="button" name="button">Find Restaurant</a>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Find Restaurant" />
```

This will post the form data to `search.php` - if you want the page to submit to itself, change `action="search.php"` to `action=""`.

Note: you will need to change your CSS to style the button in the same way.

Comment: @S.N, according to your comment you're using $_GET even though in the code you've provided us uses $_POST. If you want help, post the correct thing and provide more than "I still get the error". Change $_GET to $_POST.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the error

```
<a href="search.php" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:-10px; margin-right:0px"type="button" name="button">Find Restaurant</a>
```

Use a submit button instead of that.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Find Restaurant" />
```

And if you want to use a tag then do like this.

```
 <a href="Javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:-10px; margin-right:0px"type="button" name="button" onclick="document.formname.submit();">Find Restaurant</a>
```

Give a name to your form tags

```
<form style="margin-top:20px; margin-right:+50px" name="formname" method="post" action="search.php">
```

Both the way you can do it. But in your existing code you are not submiting the form rather you are just linked it to the file.

Answer (score 1):

remove the anchor tag from button when you are using action, you have to do something like this

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button" />
```

Comment: this is my new input istead of a element. <input type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Find Restaurant" style="margin-top:-10px; margin-right:0px" />still with error.

Comment: don't use $_GET try by using $_POST with select fields

Comment: I am getting this error now: Notice: Undefined index: select1, and the same for select2

Comment: i think you are getting the error when you refresh the page. use isset($_POST['button']){ write your php code for fields here}

Comment: @ Shahba I already have the error on my index.php without doing anything.

Comment: can you share your page live some where?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. buy using only $_POST, instead of $_get and I also removed

```
<?php 
$select1 = $_POST['select1'];
?>
```

now the error -  undefined index - is not showing up anymore, and I get the correct value in the search.php page. thanks guys for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

your updated solution i am run this problem on my computer

    
     
    Select your island
    St. Maarten
    Aruba
    Curacou
    St. Barths

```
<select name="select2"> 
<option value="SelectLoc">Select your location</option>
<option value="Philipsburg">Philipsburg</option>
<option value="SimpsonBay">Simpson Bay</option>
<option value="Maho">Maho</option>
<option value="Cupecoy">Cupecoy</option>
<option value="Middleregion">Middle region</option>
<option value="MadameEstate">Madame Estate</option>
<option value="StPeters">St. Peters</option>
<option value="DawnBeach">Dawn Beach</option>
</select>
<!--<input type="submit" name="button" value="search"  />
-->
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['select1']) && isset($_POST['select2'])) {
$select1 = $_POST['select1'];
$select2 = $_POST['select2'];
echo $select1;
echo "";
echo $select2;
}
else{
echo "not set";
}
?>
```