# how to display value from dropdown form to another php script

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html-select

this is a index.php page where i have dropdown list
when i select the value from dropdown list i wont display that value in user.php page i use javascript onchange

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Selected Dropdown Value</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function selected_region(){

            var vr = document.getElementById("region").value;

            alert("Selected region is: "+vr);

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="selected_region_form" method="POST" action="user.php">
            <?php ?>
            <select name="region" id="region" onchange="selected_region();">
                <label for="region">Odaberite zupaniju:</label>
                <option> 
                    <?php 
                    $region_data = all_regions();
                    while($region = mysqli_fetch_array($region_data)){
                            $id_region = $region['zupanija_id'];
                            $name_region = $region['naziv'];
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php $id_region; ?>"><?php echo $name_region; ?></option>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send"/>
        </form>
    </body>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the user.php script
under in td tag-s i wont display selected value from index.php

```
<?php

include('connect.php');
include('functions.php');
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>User</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>User</h1>
        <h2>selected region:</h2>
        <table border="1"> 
            <tr> 
                <td> <!-- here i need display a selected region --> <td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    <a href="index.php.">Back</a>
</html>
```

functions.php script where a fatch my query:

```
<?php

    function confirm_query($result_set){
        if(!$result_set){
            die("Query data faild!");
        }
    }

    function all_regions(){
        global $db_connection;

        $query  = "SELECT `zupanija_id`,`naziv` ";
        $query .= "FROM `zupanija` ";
        $query .= "ORDER BY `zupanija_id` ASC";
        $zupanije_data = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);
        confirm_query($zupanije_data);
        return $zupanije_data;
    }

?>
```

connection script:

```
<?php
$connect_error = 'Connection faild!';
$select_db_error = 'Database not found!';
$db_connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'iwa_2013', 'foi2013') or die($connect_error);
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($db_connection, 'iwa_2013_sk_projekt') or die($select_db_error);


//setup charset to utf-8
    mysqli_set_charset($db_connection, 'utf8');
?>
```

Comment: And how is your code not working as expected?  What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to attach an onchange event handler to your select element, then have it fire off an AJAX request to your PHP script every time the user selects something.
[sending a value from drop down box to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023987/sending-a-value-from-drop-down-box-to-another-page)

Answer (score 0):

Your form is actually submitted to the  kreiran_zahtjev.php page via the post method so the element you clicked on will be available via the $_POST variable on kreiran_zahtjev.php

Essentially, if you want to access the clicked element, all you have to do is:

```
$_POST['zupanija']
```

Also, you shouldn't use the mysql_ extension of PHP, it's insecure and deprecated. You should use either PDO or mysqli.